# Swift Core data textfield and uiimage into tableview cell

Tags: swift

Have an app where user type name and chose photo, click save and all that is going to second view into tableview cell. And i got picture in tableview cell. All is working fine, finally, i understand a lot about coredata now, but have a problem, when user type only name and NOT choose a picture and when click save, app is crashing, which is normal because tableview is expecting some image from core data, i need somehow to make, if photo is not choosed ,proceed to tableview.

i tried with this in first vc

```
if photoImage.image == nil {

newUser.setValue(textfield.text, forKey: "username")

}else{

newUser.setValue(textfield.text, forKey: "username")

let imageData = NSData(data:     UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!, 1.0)!)
newUser.setValue(imageData, forKey: "image")
}
```

it does work and i can proceed with that code to tableview cell, but now when i pick any photo, no photo is displayed ever in cell. I'm a little overwhelmed with informations about coredata, and maybe solution is really easy, but i can't find it. So how to tell xcode proceed to tableview if no photo is choosed, and so i can later chose photo if i want to.

This is code for fetching in second vc - tableview

```
let image = person.valueForKey("image") as? NSData
cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: image!)
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: why not put a default picture or default icon their. and In your code check that if your cell.ImageView is nil then use default pic.

Comment: because without photo is nill in first code i got crash if i dont choose a picture , unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in this let imageData = NSData(data:     UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!, 1.0)!)
newUser.setValue(imageData, forKey: "image")

Comment: can you provide me access to your code so I can work around with it. If you are not comfortable with that then try using an if statement that if the user has not selected a photo then save a default photo in core data. I am assuming the error arises when you try to save your selections and try to move onto the next view.

Comment: great thinking :), yea i get that erorr because of that what you talking about, will now copy paste codes

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

**Note: I am using NSUserDefaults in the example below but the concept can be applied to your situation too.**

```
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    // here I check whether my userDefaults contain any image 
    // YOU can check whether a user has selected a image or not
    if let userPhotoIsNotNil = userDefaults.objectForKey("userPhoto") as? NSData {

          let img = UIImage(data: userPhotoIsNotNil)

            userPhoto.image = img
    } else {

        // If there is no image in the userDefaults then set a default Icon
        // FOR you, if they have not selected an image then set a default one
        userPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "userDefaultIcon")

        // OR Save a default icon in userDefaults 
        // OR for you, save the default to core data
        userDefaults.setObject(yourImageFileHere, forKey: "userPhoto")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
```

You can apply the same scenario in your code. This code basically a copy paste of one of my previous projects.

I hope this kinda helps.

Comment: will try it, thank you a lot, great idea for using default pic :).

Comment: no problem mate I'm still learning it myself. :) If this works out for you then come back later and select this as an answer.

Comment: yea, no problem, with this workarround i'm sure that cell.imageview will always get a picture, default pic or user picked pic, amazing :) thanx again.